# searching a value in watch window

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm debugging c# in visual studio

I added an object to the `watch window`

Given some value, 
is there any way to search which field holds this value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Searching for text in an Object watch window in visual studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921681/searching-for-text-in-an-object-watch-window-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no such built in search functionality in the VS2010 watch window (although the watch window has a [lots of cool features](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/121623/10-Tips-you-should-know-about-Watch-Window-While-d)).

See also this unresolved question: [Searching for text in an Object watch window in visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921681/searching-for-text-in-an-object-watch-window-in-visual-studio)

However there are some commercial extensions which offers that functionality.

E.g.: Excerpt from the [OzCode](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/36925113-cdce-4953-a5d6-fb3d2912dad7) VS extension feature list:

> **Search**
>
> When debugging objects and collections, you are often looking for a specific property or field, or a value held within a property or field. Unfortunately, this usually involves either a lot of clicking and scrolling, or writing custom debug-specific code. Finding items even in simple structures is not easy, not to mention doing so in a complex object graph. With our “Search” feature, this is no longer the case.

Comment: Seems like BugAid isn't there anymore, seems like it has been taken over, been continued in by Oz-Code (http://www.oz-code.com/) or is simply gone

Answer (score 17):

#### This is now natively supported in ***Visual Studio 2019***

[image: VS Code Search]

#### Search w/ Expressions in VS 2022

You can sort of search by expressions by pinning the property you're looking for (search property name to find it), and then select "Show Pinned Member Names in Values".  Then you can search for a match in the value `prop_name = value`

[image: Search Expression]

#### Further Reading

- [Searching for objects and properties in the Watch, Autos, and Locals Window](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/enhanced-in-visual-studio-2019-search-for-objects-and-properties-in-the-watch-autos-and-locals-windows/) by
  [Leslie Richardson](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/author/lerich/)
- [Debugging > Inspect variables in the Autos and Locals windows > Search in the Autos or Locals window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/autos-and-locals-windows?view=vs-2022#search-in-the-autos-or-locals-window)

Comment: Can it support expressions? Such as `Property == value`

Comment: @MichaelFulton, updated w/ a way to accomplish search expressions in VS 2022

Comment: Thank you for this. I am currently on VS 2019 and this did exactly what I needed it to do

Answer (score 4):

I like to use the Immediate window (Debug ==> Windows ==> Immediate) and LINQ to search data structures. E.g.:

```
queries.Find(q => q.Name.Equals("HTTP_Response_Splitting"))
```