# Serialize an object to a string in one line of code for debugging in the watch window

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

How would I serialize a deep object tree to a string in the Watch window for debugging purposes in Visual Studio?

This is an expansion for one of the answers on this question: [Searching for text in an Object watch window in visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921681/searching-for-text-in-an-object-watch-window-in-visual-studio).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any POCO that implements a ToString() method will use the ToString() to show in the Watch window as follows :

```
 public class MyObject
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", Id, Name);
        }
    }
```

That being said, all you need to do is to implement the ToString() method as you see fit.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively use the DebuggerDisplayAttribute to nominate a field on your class as being the default debugger evaluation value. This means ToString() is not doing double-duty.